# lodash - transform object value to string with nested keys

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to use lodash to transform all value of object (nested key) from numberic to string, and null to blank.

Please help.

FROM:

```
{
 "item1": {
   "key1": 123,
   "key2": "str",
   "key3": null,
   "key4": [1, 1, 1],
   "nestedkey": {
      "nestkey1": {
          "nestkey2": {
              "key1": 12.34,
              "key3": null
          }
      }
   }
 }
}
```

TO:

```
{
 "item1": {
   "key1": "123",
   "key2": "str",
   "key3": "",
   "key4": [1, 1, 1],
   "nestedkey": {
      "nestkey1": {
          "nestkey2": {
              "key1": "12.34",
              "key3": ""
          }
      }
   }
 }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything at all yourself yet?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Generally you should not ask questions on SO without first demonstrating effort of your own.  Thanks, and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

```
const mapValuesDeep = (obj, cb) => {
  if (_.isArray(obj)) {
    return obj.map(innerObj => mapValuesDeep(innerObj, cb));
  } else if (_.isObject(obj)) {
    return _.mapValues(obj, val => mapValuesDeep(val, cb));
  } else if(_.isString(obj) || _.isBoolean(obj)) {
    return obj;
  } else {
    return cb(obj);
  }
};

const result = mapValuesDeep(obj, _.toString)
```

Thanks!